# Laravel 7 Browser doesn't download file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running Xampp on my windows 10 machine, and I have a file called `files.txt` inside my directory project.

[...]storage\app\public

My `config/filesystem.php` looks like:

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'permissions' => [
            'file' => [
                'public' => 0664,
                'private' => 0600,
            ],
            'dir' => [
                'public' => 0775,
                'private' => 0700,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

On my controller I am calling the file to download

```
return response()->download(storage_path("app\public\\files.txt"),'down.txt');
```

I am receiving 200 status Ok, the headers content I receive:

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=files.txt , on response on the browser Xhr devtools I could see the content of the file, but unhappy the download don't happen.

Comment: Double back splash before files.txt. change to `app\public\files.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to specify header :

```php
$content = storage_path("app\public\files.txt");
$fileName = 'down.txt';
$headers = [
  'Content-type' => 'text/plain', 
  'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $fileName),
  'Content-Length' => strlen($content)
];   

return response()->download($content,$fileName, $headers);
```

Comment: ok my friend , i'll try this way , because i have solved this issue from another way ( using a route specific to download and the parameter was filename , back soon . one moment

Comment: Hey Octet , the problem still , download dont happen , only show the content on dev tools chrome  , maybe because i'm calling this from a call ajax  .

Comment: oh I see, you have a page with a download link which call in ajax your controller which return the download response ? 
If so, I guess you can't do that. You can add a classic link with target blank to your route, the result will be the same because the new tab will auto-close on download

Comment: yep , i did this , now Works ;)

Comment: please can you post your code with solution, for " You can add a classic link with target blank to your route," i am facing the same issue